# Custom post type name and assigning custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, custom-content

I've made mistake creating custom post type. I've put:

```
register_post_type( 'Post Name', $args );
```

instead of

```
register_post_type( 'post_name', $args );
```

Now I need to assign new custom taxonomy to this post type.
Problem stars here:

```
    register_taxonomy( 'custom taxonomy', array( 'Post Name' ), $args );
```

doesn't work.

I've tried to change custom post type name to one string and then assign taxonomy and it works.

```
register_taxonomy( 'custom taxonomy', array( 'post_name' ), $args );
```

Problem is that because of existing content I can't change custom post type name like this. 
Looking for workaround that let me save my existing content.

Comment: There a a few plugins available to change the post type of a post

Comment: You can use plugins like [Convert Post Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/convert-post-types/) or [Post Type Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/)

Comment: @PieterGoosen, yes plugin can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked another option and asigned my custom taxonomy to custom post type using its name but without capitals and space.

**'postname'** works with original **'Post Name'**

So for custom post type

```
register_post_type( 'Post Name', $args );
```

I can use

```
register_taxonomy( 'custom taxonomy', array( 'postname' ), $args );
```

And it works.